# Why does the first note is the second Bach cello suite(Prelude) sound like C#?

Tags: theory, scales, key, j-s-bach, cello

Suite 2 in the Bach suites is in D minor howcome the first note sounds like C# even though its written on the 3rd line(d)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very interesting !! Just listened to the opening bars, and it's in C#minor. That's probably why it sounds like a C#, not a D. Now whether the recording has been slowed down a smidgen is conjecture, or whether the cello is actually tuned differently I don't know. So, yes it sounds like C# 'cos it is. Couldn't find one in 'Dm'.Unless, of course, the tuning was not well tempered.

Comment: Are you referring to a specific recording? Many recordings these days would be made on a Baroque cello tuned to A=415, which is one half-step lower than the "modern" tuning of A=440. This is more or less the tuning that Bach himself would have used. It is not a question of "well-tempered" or not; that refers to *temperament*, which is not much of an issue on solo cello. Rather, it is a question of the base pitch (*diapason*, or *kammerton*) used for "A" in Hz (cycles per second).

Comment: Out of several I listened to there were none in concert D as of modern tuning. When a solo instrument is played, it makes not much difference, 'D minor' becomes academic.

Comment: Then they were in concert D as of Bach's tuning, which is A=415. It makes a difference, particularly if it is a Baroque cello with sheep-gut strings rather than a modern cello with steel strings.